# With Gravity Forms, how do I make a form entry count as 2 entries based on a boolean?

Tags: forms, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm working on an event registration form with Gravity Forms. The event needs to be limited to *X* amount of registrants. Gravity Forms gives us this ability under the "Form Settings > Restrictions > Limit Number of Entries" section. As expected, each form filled out counts as 1 entry.

However, this form also has a "Bringing a Guest?" boolean (Yes or No radio buttons). If "Yes" is selected, I would like the form submission to count as 2 entries. How can this be done?

Comment: not really sure if this the best idea, but you can set the check Yes value to 2 and No value to 1, then using GF API, pull and add those values for all the form entries, then hide the form if the total value is greater than or equal to your desired registration limit, but this is assuming you know your way on PHP

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Gravity Forms built-in entry limits, you might consider using a snippet I wrote which adds support for inventory to your Gravity Forms fields. More details on the other side of this link:

http://gravitywiz.com/better-inventory-with-gravity-forms/